# A question about the famous $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I know this is a famous series.

I encountered it the first time while studying Cauchy sequences and I can prove it diverges using Cauchy criterion.

But today I discovered something that made laugh:

Just write it as: $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, we easily see that $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is the smallest term is the left sum. So: $ \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$  but $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}$, hence $ \sqrt{n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. This clearly diverges.

Is this correct or am I missing something? Because I remember that my professor went through a hassle to prove that it diverges. This is was so easy that I feel I must've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: You didn't make any mistake. $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k} \ge \sqrt n$$ is correct

Comment: @Crostul Isn't this beautiful :)

Comment: You can use this argument to prove divergence of $\sum 1/n^a$ for $0<a<1$. Notice that the argument fails for $a=1$, but nevertheless the harmonic series diverges even if this argument does not apply.

Comment: Perhaps you don't remember correctly about your professor. Let's ask him, may be, what he thinks about it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Bitte? Was wollen Sie sagen?

Comment: On the other hand, this series converges [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371488/prove-that-u-n-frac1-sqrtn-left-frac1-sqrt1-frac1-sqrt).